# .htaccess issue with redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have just setup a new local site (localhost/pfb.net/) which has been cloned from a source-control site.

The coding that was done on it was pretty awful so all css/js point to /inc/js or /inc/css but what I need to do is this: /pfb.net/inc/js or /pfb.net/inc/css

So I guess the easiest way of doing that without messing around with the code would be .htaccess.

Anybody know how to do this?

I am really terrible with setting it up.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Sorry I did forget to mention that the .htaccess would be located in /pfb.net/ not in the root of the directory. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you sure messing with .htaccess file won't mess things even further?

Comment: Considering there is no current .htaccess file then I'm sure it'll be okay, and its the only way I can think about doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the rules are fairly straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^inc/js/(.+)  /pfb.net/inc/js/$1
RewriteRule ^inc/css/(.+) /pfb.net/inc/css/$1
```

Comment: Thanks Salman A, I tried that to no avail. I did just update my question if that makes any difference? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, the location of .htaccess file _does_ matter. The thing is: when apache encounters a request for `/inc/js/` it will process .htaccess files inside `/`, `/inc/` and `/inc/js/`. The `/pfb.net/.htaccess` will _never_ fire!

Comment: Okay well I can move it to the root dir, it would have just been easier to do it within /pfb.net/ but I have tried it in the root dir too, it didn't seem to work :/

Comment: See revised answer (i) apache did not like the `#` comments (ii) removed leading `/` (iii) added RewriteEngine On

Comment: Hey sorry I didnt get back last night, I went to bed, I was shattered. That didn't work still btw. :/ Thanks anyway!